# "I considered stopping being friends" vs "I considered stop being friends"?

Tags: past-tense

I was telling a story to a friend about a group of friends doing something to me in the past that made me consider not being friends with them anymore. At the time I phrased it like this: "I considerd stop being friends with them", but then I wondered, doesn't it make more sense for it to be "I considered stopping being friends with them"? Can anyone in here help me understand which form is correct and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I considered stopping* / **stop being friends with them.*

The catenative verb "consider" requires only a gerund-participial clause as complement: an infinitival clause would be ungrammatical.

One reason for this restriction may be attributed to the fact that most often "consider" takes a noun phrase complement, as in *I consider him a fool*, and the fact that gerund-participials are more like NPs than infinitivals are is seen in the fact that they can invert with the subject in interrogatives.

Comment: I do not understand this answer. What is the asterisk for? Of course, an infinitival clause is not grammatical. It is not true that "consider" most often takes a noun phrase complement (I consider him a fool). The verb consider is often following by a gerund phrase.

Comment: @Lambie The asterisk (or star) is commonly used to mark an expression as ungrammatical. I starred the verb "stop" because it is ungrammatical. As I explained, gerund-participial clauses are more like NPs than infinitivals, which may well explain why "consider" takes only such clauses and not infinitivals. This is all part of providing a plausible answer to the OP's question of _why_ "stopping is correct, but not "stop".

Comment: @BillJ I understand why is not correct, but I would like to ask you something, how can I know what type of clause can a verb take as a complement? I know now that "consider" only takes gerund-participial because you told me so, but how could I learn this information otherwise?

Comment: @zlaaemi This should help:  [link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs)

Answer (score 0):

Please review verbs that take ING. *Stop, start, commence. finish, and end* (sometimes)

So, "I considered **stopping being** friends with them". is, in fact, accurate.
Both the verb *consider* and *stop* take ing for these meanings.

"I considered being friends with them."

*I stopped being friends with them last year*. But we would probably say:    *I considered no longer being friends with x.*

**This is because having two verbs with ING can be considered heavy.**

To be friends with someone.

The verb consider and imagine can be followed by a gerund or a noun phrase. But the meaning changes: [consider and imagine](https://www.grammaring.com/to-infinitive-or-gerund-consider-imagine)

Comment: The form of the verb "stop" is not determined by its complement clause but by the verb "consider", which is restricted to taking gerund-participial complements only, hence "stopping", not "stop". As it happens, the catenative verb "stop" is also restricted to gerund-participial complements, but that serves only to explain the form "being" (as opposed to "be"), not the form "stopping".

Comment: @BillJ What is concatenative is this: consider is followed by ing, thus, *stopping*, which in turn takes ing, so *being*. In fact, any combination of stop and consider take ing: I considered stopping the lessons. I stopped considering the lessons.

Comment: What I said is perfectly OK. What is not OK is the first sentence of your answer which talks of the verbs "stop" etc. taking _ing_ forms (thus explaining why "being" is the correct form). That's not what the OP asked about; they asked why "stopping" is correct and not "stop", the answer to which I  explained in my answer and again in my comment above. Once more, the reason is that "consider" is a catenative verb that permits only gerund-participial complements. Further, you made no mention of the term 'catenative' construction, yet is a vital part of explaining why only "stopping" is correct.

Comment: You're still missing the point. The OP's question was about "stopping" vs "stop", the answer to which lies in the fact that "consider" is here a catenative verb which takes a only a gerund-participial clause as complement. It has nothing to do with the verbs "stop", "start" etc. They determine the form of the verb that follows them, not the one that precedes them. That's how the catenative construction works.

Comment: catenative is meaningless here as it means **three things**, to-infinitive, bare infinitive or present participle/gerund. Three things. Two of which could apply here. To wit:  I considered stopping for a coffee. I considered him to be the right person for the job. Both those are "catenative". Ergo, catenative does not explain this.

Comment: It's not meaningless -- it's the usual way of explaining why "stopping" is correct, but "stop" isn't. Do you have a better way? Of course 'catenative' explains things. Catenative verbs are restricted to non-finite complements, and "consider" is one of those that more specifically is restricted to gerund-participials in the particular kind of sentence cited by the OP (called a 'simple catenative').

Comment: Concatenative verbs **can be followed** by a to-infinitive OR a gerund. Sometimes, with a difference in meaning. So saying these are concatenative explains nothing.

Comment: Native speakers generally know instinctively which verbs take which complements, but learners don't -- they have to refer to an appropriate chart in order to make that determination, and they need to know that the name of that chart is ‘catenatives verbs’, or similar --  a simple and obvious learning process. The OP knew nothing about catenatives before I set them straight, but now they can not only access the relevant chart and make the correct selection with confidence, but also know why they are doing it.